# Ordinal Encoder with Specific order include NAN

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nan, ordinal

Let say that I have this example dataset

```
test = {'Education': ['High School', 'Uneducated', 'Graduate', 'College', np.nan, 'High School'],
        'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F']}
```

and the outcome will be like this, right

```
    Education   Gender
    High School M
    Uneducated  F
    Graduate    M
    College     F
    NaN         M
    High School F
```

All I want to do is, specify the 'Education' column to be ordinal, with this code,

```
edu = ['Uneducated','High School', 'College', 'Graduate']
oe_edu = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[edu])
test['Education'] = oe_edu.fit_transform(test[['Education']])
```

but I have a problem with the NaN values, and I still want to include NaN values, so later I can use imputation
(my scikit-learn version is 1.02 so it can handle NaN if default categories)

So, the final output to be like this

```
    Education   Gender
    1.0         M
    0.0         F
    3.0         M
    2.0         F
    NaN         M
    1.0         F
```

maybe it will work if include this paramater 'handle_unknown' and 'unknown_value', but I'm not sure how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I got it by myself

```
edu = ['Uneducated','High School', 'College', 'Graduate']
oe_edu = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[edu], handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=np.nan)
test['Education'] = oe_edu.fit_transform(test[['Education']])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
edu = ['Uneducated','High School', 'College', 'Graduate']
test['cat'] = pd.Categorical(test['Education'], categories=edu, ordered=True)

print(test)
     Education Gender          cat
0  High School      M  High School
1   Uneducated      F   Uneducated
2     Graduate      M     Graduate
3      College      F      College
4          NaN      M          NaN
5  High School      F  High School

print(test['cat'].cat.codes)
0    1
1    0
2    3
3    2
4   -1
5    1
dtype: int8
```